# pass parameters to function in jquery custom widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass parameters to function , on click of button in my jquery custom widget.

```
// bind click events on the button to the random method
        this._on(this.captureBtn, {
            // _on won't call random when widget is disabled
            click: "_getImage"
        });
```

I want to pass parameters to the getImage function. Please help.

Comment: Why is `"_getImage"` in quotes? What does `this._on` look like?

Comment: this is the tutorial in jquery custom widget, which refers to use this way of binding events. Please check http://jqueryui.com/widget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely solution to your problem is to pass it in through an anonymous function.  This way the function won't be evaluated at runtime.

```
    this._on(this.captureBtn, {
        // _on won't call random when widget is disabled
        click: function() {
            getImage(param1, param2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've edited it to reflect the vagueness but passing it in a closure will answer the issue of how generally to pass functions as object properties without them being evaluated at run time, which I would guess to be the issue.